# Canon MF633cdw - How to install Scanner

Tags: printing, scanner, canon

I can't install the scanner. It's a multifuncional Canon MF633cdw. How can I do that? HELP!!!

Comment: Operating system and version, please!

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS

Comment: Did you install the [driver](https://www.canon-europe.com/support/consumer_products/products/fax__multifunctionals/laser/laserbase_mf_series/i-sensys_mf633cdw.html?type=drivers&language=en&os=linux)?

Comment: Yes, but nothing happens. Still not working